# Comment editing timeout well before "link" is removed

Tags: feature-request, rate-limiting, comment-edits

I attempted to edit a comment close to the 5 minute timeout and was denied the opportunity to Save. I cancelled and added a new comment.

While I was watching, the edit link of the previous comment didn't go away until it said I edited it 7 minutes ago.

IMHO the edit link could go when it says edited 5 minutes ago, or at least by the time it says 6 minutes ago.

I've changed this to a feature-request because the test comment I added to this question still shows the edit link 10 minutes after I added it. Clearly the link is not currently removed until a page refresh.

Comment: This comment is trying to test what happens when I don't try to edit it, but I am watching TV...

Comment: This might be a case: Within 5 minutes period you may clicked on edit while editing you may crossed 5 minutes so it gives this error. (This happens too many times with me.) :)

Comment: +1 Edit link doesn't disappear even after [6 minutes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kbCkI.png), [7 minutes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TYjNi.png), [8 minutes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FJwuW.png), [**12 minutes**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aGABK.png) or [**18 minutes**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/znYhK.png).

Comment: let me try.... testing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bad idea. I don't like elements on the page suddenly disappearing.

Also, there's nothing like that anywhere on Stack Exchange. For example, vote arrows won't disappear when the vote locks. Edit link won't disappear when an edit is suggested by someone else on the post you read.

You see the error when doing the action. That's consistent, and that's a good user experience in my opinion. If you want to see "fresh" status of the page, simply reload. It's one click/keypress away.