# Will asking a really good question get you more chances to ask more questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderators, account-suspension, gaming-the-system

Why am II still getting this warning after coming back from a suspension?
Should I get a fresh start? Is this probation temporary?

Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity."

How important is getting up votes for this question after a warning like this? Does a better received question at this point get you another chance to ask a question?

Comment: Upvotes don't do much (if anything) for the post-ban algorithms as far as I know *once you have at least one net*, so have a positive score makes a difference, and a negative score makes a difference the other way, but it doesn't make much difference whether a question is +10 or +1.

Comment: The linked duplicate does say *But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.*

Comment: FYI: [Harassing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305872/duplicates-on-meta-sites-sum-the-votes/305876?noredirect=1#comment1007452_305876) a user in a comment and then serially downvoting their posts is not a good way to get this question reopened. Also, it's wrong to assume that I downvoted.

Comment: see [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231118/165773): "The specific criteria for these aren't public largely for the same reasons the quality block criteria aren't public, but let's just say that folks who are nearing hitting a block will be getting a heads up and some instructions first."

Comment: wonder if you checked the referred link (only question title talks about new users, which is a bit misleading because the answer covers much more general case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading through the question - I guess you know where you went wrong. *That* is really really important. In fact that is what the goal of your question ban is, especially in terms of meta.

It's not about *one* question. It's about working out what's gone wrong so far and working on fixing it. Sounds a bit trite but *personal growth* overall would help more than getting upvotes on *this specific question* so you can ask the *next* question. Especially on meta, it's about getting an audience and a result over the question itself.

That said, it's pretty darned hard to get question banned on meta so it might not just be that - you have some questions that are [on your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/312109/muze) that are on topic, but poorly received

So... for you, as per your admission...

It's almost as important to keep things on the *right site* as it is to ask *great* questions. You've been around the network a while, and well, have no excuse not to know what's [on topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what isn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

I think the critical skill here isn't asking *exceptional* questions. It's being aware of the folks around you, work out what's ok as far as questions go (and admittedly this isn't something that can be spelled out), and ask relevant, clear and useful questions.

I'd also add, that more than as a place to *ask* questions, consider SE as a place to *pick up* and *share* knowledge.